Handwritten Number and Text Recognition
I am working on a project where I have successfully detected cells from a tabular image and in each cell I am trying to detect the written numbers and texts as well but I have failed numerous times after trying so many options.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zEwtZHwLJ6_a7LGjLy0D6AalrDWJPE2x?usp=drive_link
Here I have attached my last attempt using pytesseract even though I know pytesseract is not good for handwritten detection. But still its detecting like 5 for 51, 79 for 71.
!apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr

from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import cv2
import pytesseract

def recognize_digit(image):
    # Preprocess the image for OCR
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=0.9, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    equalized = clahe.apply(gray)
    threshold = cv2.threshold(equalized, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(threshold, h=0)
    
    # Remove horizontal lines
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (24,1))
    detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)
        cv2.drawContours(denoised, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
        cv2.drawContours(threshold, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
    
    # Remove vertical lines
    vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,25))
    detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 5)
        cv2.drawContours(denoised, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
        cv2.drawContours(threshold, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
    
    # Display the preprocessed image
    cv2_imshow(denoised)

    # Apply OCR using Tesseract
    config = "--psm 7 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789"
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(denoised, config=config)

    return text.strip()

# Read the image
image_path = '51.png'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Define the region of interest (coordinates of the desired region)
x, y, w, h = 4, 4, 800, 100

# Crop the image to the defined region
roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# Recognize the handwritten digit within the cropped region
recognized_digit = recognize_digit(roi)

# Print the recognized digit
print("Recognized digit:", recognized_digit)



What resolution are your images?  Are they sloppy?  Do you have a sample to show us?  Handwriting recognition is far from an established science.

yes but how can I show it.. I am new user of stack overflow

You can edit your question, but it's possible you don't have enough reputation to embed an image.  You can include a link to one, however.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have added a google drive folder link, please check out and help if possible @TimRoberts
